# Does flash suffer performance-wise from the x and y being too large?

Tags: flash, actionscript

Let's say a movieclip inside another movieclip has a x of 9000. Is that bad? Is there a cap? Thanks

Comment: How large is too large? Too large to be anywhere close to stage boundaries, or too large for the Flash runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a limit applied to `Number` which is what type `x` and `y` are. It's not bad to have a large value.

[See here about Number.MAX_VALUE](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Number.html#MAX_VALUE).